# How can I fix stuttering and lag issues in Deus Ex HR Director's Cut?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Just got this game of the sale, looking forward to playing it.

Unfortunately, I've received massive stutering and lag issues.  I have a pretty amazing gaming rig, as I can run BL2, AC4 at max to high settings with no stutter.  So this shouldn't be an issue for me.

From what I can tell online, there's also very few solutions out there.  One of the options was to edit registry settings, but that doesn't change a thing still.

Any way I can optimize the game to remove this "lag"? It's plenty annoying, and the problem doesnt seem to go away even when I lower the settings down to nothing.

Comment: I also have been having this problem. Tried all the registry fixes from around the internet and they don't help. It's quite annoying since I could run the original 60+ fps with maxed settings and was really looking forward to this one.

Comment: @Dustin Exactly my sentiment.  I think I managed to get things smoothed out by going into my Nvida Control Panel and making sure the game was manually using the graphics card, but even then I would still get these constant stutters.

Comment: Looks like we have more than one problem in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a NVidia graphics card (which is what normally causes this problem) you can make the following registry change to resolve this issue:

Open the Windows registry editor:

- Open the Start Menu
- Type in `regedit.exe`

For the original release:

- Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HR`

For the Director's Cut:

- Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HRDC` for Director's Cut

Change this value to 1 to disable graphics optimisations:

- Set `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_PREVENT_INTERNAL_TH­READING_OPTIMIZATIONS` to 1

Alternatively, if the above doesn't resolve the issue for you, you can also try setting the following values as well - this should work regardless of graphics card vendor;

- In `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HRDC`, locate `AllowJobStealing` and set it to 0

Finally, specifically for owners of NVidia graphics cards;

- In `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HRDC\Graphics`, locate `AtiForceFetch4` and set it to 0

For the original release of Deus Ex: Human Revolution, change the above registry keys from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HRDC` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HR`.

Comment: I've done that before, from what I can find online, and I still get massive stuttering issues. If I run in a straight line without looking around I can get no lag, but once i turn a corner or look around, it stutters up again

Comment: Added a couple more things to test

Comment: Tried those, still getting random framerate drops for same reasons.  Otherwise, everything else is fluid.  computer isn't overheating, and I'm using a fan, so i don't think there's any problem with cpu temp

Answer (score 1):

A couple more solutions from around the internet, which I'll offer up. They didn't work for me but apparently they work for some people.

1. Run Google Chrome in background
2. Use the app from http://www.lucashale.com/timer-resolution/ and set it to the highest setting, it changes the timer
3. Change from fullscreen to windowed, and then alt-tab back to the game again so it'll go fullscreen
4. Turn off triple buffering

Love to see some more suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Nvidia users can also try this (and it works for all games):

- Disable in game VSYNC
- Enable VSYNC IN Nvidia Control Panel (On or Adaptive).

It can even double the frame rate in some games (for example WRC4).